# Cast mpz_class to int

Tags: c++, gmp

Using gmp, I declare:

```
mpz_class x = 0;
```

but now if I want to use x as an index of an array, like so:

```
textArray[x];
```

I get this error "error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'testArray[x]'"

So how do I get around this?

Comment: What is the testArray ?

Comment: char testArray[] = "0123456789abcdef";

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual `operator[]` takes a `size_t`. You need to convert your `mpz_class` instance in a compatible type:

```
textArray[x.get_ui()];
```

Note that this will lead to trouble if `x` is greater than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` (check with `x.fits_ulong_p())`. Note that `mpz_class` is also most-likely not very well suited for that task. Ask yourself: should an index be arbitrary large?

See also:

- http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers